# Why is my jquery ajax not working on my page and page is also refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new in the area of jQuery/Ajax and my little test function doesn't work. And my page is also refreshingcan any one help me

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ser_itm").change(function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bar_pull.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#tbl").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you should not use absolute path for the file, it must be running on server

Comment: Also, you need to pass the reference of the function to the handler, not the result of the function - remove the brackets at the end, eg. `$('.linkDetails').on('click', getDetailsFromServer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm going to try and explain these points more clearly:

---

You cannot access `C:\Users\yah\Desktop\text.txt`. This is a [server side path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side), your javascript runs on the [client side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side). So this needs to be a path you can browse to in your browser, something like `/pathinURL/text.txt`. How you do this is dependant on your hosting technology, etc.

---

Your call backs are also wrong,

```
$('.linkDetails').on('click', getDetailsFromServer());
```

&

```
success: postToPage()
```

these will execute the function when they are hit, (well it actually binds the function result) not when the event happens. To make these work you need to remove the braces:

```
$('.linkDetails').on('click', getDetailsFromServer);
```

&

```
success: postToPage
```

this then hooks up the actual functions as function pointers and thus the actual functions will be fired when you want them to be.

so your final code will look like:

```
$('.linkDetails').on('click', getDetailsFromServer);

function getDetailsFromServer() {

   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/someURL/text.txt',
       success: postToPage
   });
}

function postToPage(data) {

   $('.textDetails').text(data);
   console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: So, i uploaded the file on my localhost and it finally works. Wow, i really feel a bit stupid now. However, i think i have to practise alot till i really can create own webpages. Thanks for the really fast help to all.

Comment: Don't feel stupid, you learn and get better. Everyone makes the same mistakes at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the nice words. But i have another short question - is there any policy which is helping to understand this topic even better?

Comment: Your best resource for jQuery is the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). If I'm using a method I've not used before or just as a refresh, I always check the documentation before using it.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the function, not the result of the function call:

```
$('.linkDetails').on('click', getDetailsFromServer);
```

Apply the same to your AJAX success callback:

```
success: postToPage
```

Also, the `getDetailsFromServer()` function needs to be defined before you bind it to an event. Move the function declaration before your `.on('click', ...)` call.

Answer (score 2):

what Arun P Johny said is right! but your code has another probloem

```
$('.linkDetails').on('click', getDetailsFromServer);
```

try above

Comment: Same problem with the ajax callback as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) implemented by browsers prevents local file system urls... if the page and the files are in same folders it might work.

See [SOP for file URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs) for FF